# Standard way to tag theological beliefs?

Tags: discussion

This is related to [Christianity.SE Statistics](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/are-there-any-christianityse-community-statistics)

I'm wondering if there's a standard way for voluntarily labeling one's theological beliefs. For example, in my profile page, I've labeled myself as pre-trib, pre-millenial, and predestination.

I completely understand why people would want to not do this (and thus the voluntary nature); but I think it could potentially be helpful -- since this way, when reading a response, I can click on the person's profile, and know what theological beliefs they're coming from.

### Question:

Is there a "standard way" to tag one's theological beliefs?

Is this even a good idea? Or is this equally bad as Christianity.SE statistics?

Comment: no standards that we've set out. Doesn't hurt to ID your position in your profile *but* holding a positiong does not preclude you from answering form a different position so I can understand why someone would not want to ID their position outright

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1581/the-census